# How to solve this arithmetic expression puzzle in Prolog?

Tags: python, prolog, constraints

I have a programming problem 
(https://blog.svpino.com/2015/05/08/solution-to-problem-5-and-some-other-thoughts-about-this-type-of-questions):

> Write a program that outputs all possibilities to put + or - or nothing between 
>   the numbers 1, 2, ..., 9 (in this order) such that the result is
>   always 100. E.g.: 1 + 2 + 34 – 5 + 67 – 8 + 9 = 100.

I solved this problem with Python to get **11 answers**:

```
import itertools   
for operator in [p for p in itertools.product(['+','-',''], repeat=8)]:
    values = zip([str(x) for x in range(1, length+1)], operator) + ['9']
    code = ''.join(itertools.chain(*values))
    if 100 == eval(code):
        print "%s = %d" % (code, eval(code))
```

This is my second Python code that is longer (https://gist.github.com/prosseek/41201d6508f01cf1643e):

```
[1, 2, 34, -5, 67, -8, 9]
[1, 23, -4, 56, 7, 8, 9]
[12, 3, -4, 5, 67, 8, 9]
[123, -4, -5, -6, -7, 8, -9]
[1, 23, -4, 5, 6, 78, -9]
[12, 3, 4, 5, -6, -7, 89]
[12, -3, -4, 5, -6, 7, 89]
[123, -45, -67, 89]
[123, 45, -67, 8, -9]
[1, 2, 3, -4, 5, 6, 78, 9]
[123, 4, -5, 67, -89]
```

I also found a proposed solution in Prolog
(http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/358tnp/five_programming_problems_every_software_engineer/cr2dvsz):

```
sum([Head|Tail],Signs,Result) :-
   sum(Head,Tail,Signs,Result).
sum(X,[],[],X).

sum(First,[Second|Tail],['+'|Signs],Result) :-
   Head is First + Second,
   sum(Head,Tail,Signs,Result).
sum(First,[Second|Tail],['-'|Signs],Result) :-
   Head is First - Second,
   sum(Head,Tail,Signs,Result).
sum(First,[Second|[Third|Tail]],['+'|[''|Signs]],Result) :- 
   C    is Second*10+Third, 
   Head is First + C, 
   sum(Head,Tail,Signs,Result).
sum(First,[Second|[Third|Tail]],['-'|[''|Signs]],Result) :-
   C    is Second*10+Third,
   Head is First - C,
   sum(Head,Tail,Signs,Result).
```

However, this gives **only 4 solutions** (not 11, as expected):

```
?- sum([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],X,100).
X = [+, +, -,+, +, +,'',+] ;
X = [+, +,'',-, + '', -,+] ;
X = [+,'', -,+, +, +,'',-] ;
X = [+,'', -,+ '', +, +,+] ;
false.
```

This is because the `''` does not appear as the first list item. So the solutions `[12,...]` and `[123,...]` are skipped.

I tried adding `sum(First,[Second|Tail],[''|Signs],Result) :- Head is First*10 + Second, sum(Head,Tail,Signs,Result).`,
but doing so it returns **15 solutions**, not 11.

The explanation says that with the wrong interpretation `1+23` to `((1)+2)*10+3`.

```
?- sum([1,2,3], [+,''], Result). 
Result = 33.
```

Then, how to solve this issue in Prolog? How to teach Prolog `1 + 23` is `24` in this example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the counterpart to Python eval could be implemented with `read_term/3` and `is/2`, or

```
give_100(A) :-
    generate(1, S),
    atomic_list_concat(S, A),
    read_term_from_atom(A, T, []),
    T =:= 100.

generate(9, [9]).
generate(N, [N|Ns]) :-
    N < 9, sep(N, Ns).

sep(N, L) :-
    ( L = [+|Ns] ; L = [-|Ns] ; L = Ns ),
    M is N+1,
    generate(M, Ns).
```

Sample query:

```
?- give_100(X).
X = '1+2+3-4+5+6+78+9' ;
X = '1+2+34-5+67-8+9' ;
X = '1+23-4+5+6+78-9' ;
X = '1+23-4+56+7+8+9' ;
X = '12+3+4+5-6-7+89' ;
X = '12+3-4+5+67+8+9' ;
X = '12-3-4+5-6+7+89' ;
X = '123+4-5+67-89' ;
X = '123+45-67+8-9' ;
X = '123-4-5-6-7+8-9' ;
X = '123-45-67+89' ;
false.
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg), we first define [nonterminal](http://www.metalevel.at/dcg.html) `sep//0`:

```
sep --> "+" | "-" | "".
```

Then, we run the following query (using [`phrase/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=phrase/2), `sep//0`, [`read_from_codes/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=codesio:read_from_codes/2), and [`(=:=)/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%3D:%3D%29/2)):

```
?- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes,chars).
true.

?- phrase(("1",sep,"2",sep,"3",sep,"4",sep,"5",sep,"6",sep,"7",sep,"8",sep,"9"),Cs),
   read_from_codes(Cs,Expr),
   Expr =:= 100.
  Cs = [1,+,2,+,3,-,4,+,5,+,6,+,7,8,+,9], Expr = 1+2+3-4+5+6+78+9
; Cs = [1,+,2,+,3,4,-,5,+,6,7,-,8,+,9],   Expr = 1+2+34-5+67-8+9
; Cs = [1,+,2,3,-,4,+,5,+,6,+,7,8,-,9],   Expr = 1+23-4+5+6+78-9
; Cs = [1,+,2,3,-,4,+,5,6,+,7,+,8,+,9],   Expr = 1+23-4+56+7+8+9
; Cs = [1,2,+,3,+,4,+,5,-,6,-,7,+,8,9],   Expr = 12+3+4+5-6-7+89
; Cs = [1,2,+,3,-,4,+,5,+,6,7,+,8,+,9],   Expr = 12+3-4+5+67+8+9
; Cs = [1,2,-,3,-,4,+,5,-,6,+,7,+,8,9],   Expr = 12-3-4+5-6+7+89
; Cs = [1,2,3,+,4,-,5,+,6,7,-,8,9],       Expr = 123+4-5+67-89
; Cs = [1,2,3,+,4,5,-,6,7,+,8,-,9],       Expr = 123+45-67+8-9
; Cs = [1,2,3,-,4,-,5,-,6,-,7,+,8,-,9],   Expr = 123-4-5-6-7+8-9
; Cs = [1,2,3,-,4,5,-,6,7,+,8,9],         Expr = 123-45-67+89
; false.
```

Comment: Use `:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).` to make answers more readable.

Comment: @false. Thx! Better now.

Answer (score 2):

Quite the same as CapelliC's solution, but works with SWI-Prolog and module lambda:

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

sum_100(Atom) :-
    L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    O = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H,' '],
    maplist(\X^member(X, [+,-,' ']), O),
    foldl(\X^Y^Z^T^(Y = ' '
                    ->  append(Z,[X], T)
                    ;   append(Z,[X,Y], T)), L, O, [], Expr),
    atomic_list_concat(Expr, Atom),
    term_to_atom(Term, Atom),
    Term =:= 100.
```

Sample query:

```
?- sum_100(X).
X = '1+2+3-4+5+6+78+9' ;
X = '1+2+34-5+67-8+9' ;
X = '1+23-4+5+6+78-9' ;
X = '1+23-4+56+7+8+9' ;
X = '12+3+4+5-6-7+89' ;
X = '12+3-4+5+67+8+9' ;
X = '12-3-4+5-6+7+89' ;
X = '123+4-5+67-89' ;
X = '123+45-67+8-9' ;
X = '123-4-5-6-7+8-9' ;
X = '123-45-67+89' ;
false.
```