# Arithmetic puzzle prolog

Tags: prolog

I have to put + and - between the numbers in that list to get the provided number. For example something like 12-34 = -22. I have done it like this:

```
arit(L, Ls, S) :- arit(L, Ls, S, 0).
arit([], [], R, R).

arit([E|L], Ls, R, S) :- 
    S1 is S + E, 
    Ls = [+|[E|Ns]], 
    arit(L, Ns, R, S1).

arit([E|L], Ls, R, S) :- 
    S1 is S - E, 
    Ls = [-|[E|Ns]], 
    arit(L, Ns, R, S1).


arit([E|L], Ls, R, S) :- 
    S1 is (S*10 + E), 
    Ls=[E|Ns], 
    arit(L, Ns, R, S1).
```

It works, but it has duplicates in answer (like 1+2+3 and +1+2+3). Maybe someone has a tip how to optimize it? EDIT. This code doesn't work at all, check out the answer.

Comment: Take a look ar this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30134535/how-to-solve-this-arithmetic-expression-puzzle-in-prolog/30139958#30139958 Not exactly the same problem but the same idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your code doesn't work as it should. To confirm this fact, try the following query:

```
?- put_arit2([1,2,3,4], L, 22).
false.
```

As can be easily checked, `[-,1,2,+,3,4]` would be the correct answer.

So, I suggest the following solution (in SWI-Prolog):

- Define a predicate that can generate all possible lists (with operators).
- Transform each possible list into a correspondent arithmetic expression, and check whether it has the desired value.

```
% putop(+List, -ListWithOperators)

putop([], []).
putop(L, [O|D]) :-
    member(O, [+,-]),
    append([X|A], B, L), % split list into two sublists, such that first one is not empty 
    append([X|A], C, D), % append first sublist with the sublist that will be obtained recursively
    putop(B, C).

% putop(+List, -ListWithOperators, +DesiredValue)

putop(L, E, V) :-
     putop(L, E),                   % obtain list with operators
     atomic_list_concat(E, A),      % transform list into an atom
     read_term_from_atom(A, T, []), % transfom atom into a term
     V is T.                        % check whether term has the desired value
```

Examples:

```
?- putop([1,2,3,4], L, 22).
L = [-, 1, 2, +, 3, 4] ;
false.

?- putop([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], L, 4).
L = [+, 1, +, 2, -, 3, 4, +, 5, +, 6, +, 7, +, 8, +, 9] ;
L = [+, 1, 2, +, 3, -, 4, +, 5, -, 6, -, 7, -, 8, +, 9] ;
L = [+, 1, 2, +, 3, -, 4, -, 5, +, 6, -, 7, +, 8, -, 9] ;
L = [+, 1, 2, -, 3, +, 4, +, 5, -, 6, -, 7, +, 8, -, 9] ;
L = [+, 1, 2, -, 3, +, 4, -, 5, +, 6, +, 7, -, 8, -, 9] ;
L = [+, 1, 2, -, 3, +, 4, 5, -, 6, 7, +, 8, +, 9] ;
L = [+, 1, 2, -, 3, -, 4, -, 5, -, 6, -, 7, +, 8, +, 9] ;
L = [+, 1, 2, -, 3, 4, -, 5, 6, -, 7, +, 8, 9] ;
L = [-, 1, +, 2, +, 3, 4, +, 5, 6, -, 7, 8, -, 9] ;
L = [-, 1, +, 2, 3, +, 4, 5, +, 6, -, 7, 8, +, 9] ;
L = [-, 1, -, 2, +, 3, 4, -, 5, +, 6, 7, -, 8, 9] ;
L = [-, 1, -, 2, 3, -, 4, +, 5, 6, -, 7, -, 8, -, 9] ;
L = [-, 1, 2, +, 3, +, 4, +, 5, -, 6, -, 7, +, 8, +, 9] ;
L = [-, 1, 2, +, 3, +, 4, -, 5, +, 6, +, 7, -, 8, +, 9] ;
L = [-, 1, 2, +, 3, -, 4, +, 5, +, 6, +, 7, +, 8, -, 9] ;
L = [-, 1, 2, +, 3, -, 4, -, 5, -, 6, 7, +, 8, 9] ;
L = [-, 1, 2, -, 3, -, 4, +, 5, -, 6, +, 7, +, 8, +, 9] ;
L = [-, 1, 2, -, 3, 4, +, 5, 6, -, 7, -, 8, +, 9] ;
false.
```

**[EDIT]** If you don't want to use the built-in predicates `atomic_list_concat/2` and `read_term_from_atom/3`, then you need to create your own predicate to evaluate lists of digits and operators.

```
putop(L, E, V) :-
     putop(L, E),
     evaluate(E, V).

putop([], []).
putop(L, [O|D]) :-
    member(O, [+,-]),
    append([X|A], B, L),
    append([X|A], C, D),
    putop(B, C).

evaluate(List, Value) :-
    evaluate(List, 0, Value).

evaluate([], Value, Value).
evaluate([Operator|List], Accumulator, Value) :-
    operand(List, 0, Operand, Rest),
    add(Operator, Accumulator, Operand, NewAccumulator),
    evaluate(Rest, NewAccumulator, Value).

operand([], Accumulator, Accumulator, []).
operand([+|Rest], Accumulator, Accumulator, [+|Rest]).
operand([-|Rest], Accumulator, Accumulator, [-|Rest]).
operand([Digit|Rest], Accumulator, Value, List) :-
    Digit \= +,
    Digit \= -,
    NewAccumulator is 10*Accumulator + Digit,
    operand(Rest, NewAccumulator, Value, List).

add(+, Accumulator, Operand, NewAccumulator) :-
    NewAccumulator is Accumulator + Operand.
add(-, Accumulator, Operand, NewAccumulator) :-
    NewAccumulator is Accumulator - Operand.
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't check for minuses and then two numbers.. Yeah your solution is great but I'm trying to do it without any prolog predicates (atomic_list_concat and etc). So i'm thinking it will reduce solutions, but for starter what if I could only put a symbol after first number, after first element of a list? Maybe you know how I could do that? I'm pretty new to prolog, so it sucks to get stuck on these kind of basic tasks.

Comment: Now I checked it out with morning vision, oh god, my solution is soo not working.

Comment: @LorusIndicus See "Edit" in my answer.

Comment: yeah, I came up with similar solution today, thank you so much for the help.